# Jsf2 Richfaces render Question

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

I am using richfaces4 and i have a question about rerendering components.

When i rerender my "link_panel" every row of the datatable will rerender its "link_panel". How can i change this behavior? I would like to rerender just tze current output panel and not for the complete datatable.

greetings, m

```
<rich:column rendered="#{userBean.renderLinkLinks}">
<f:facet name="header">
    Verlinkt
</f:facet>
<center>
    <a4j:outputPanel id="link_panel">
        <a4j:outputPanel rendered="#{!linkBean.isLinkedWithLerneinheit(lerneinheit)}">
            <h:outputLink > 
                <h:outputText value="Link"/>
                <a4j:ajax event="click" listener="#{linkBean.linkSelectionWithLerneinheit(lerneinheit)}" render="link_panel"/> 
            </h:outputLink>
        </a4j:outputPanel>
        <a4j:outputPanel id="unlink_panel" rendered="#{link    <rich:column rendered="#{userBean.renderLinkLinks}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        Verlinkt
    </f:facet>
    <center>
        <a4j:outputPanel id="link_panel">
            <a4j:outputPanel rendered="#{!linkBean.isLinkedWithLerneinheit(lerneinheit)}">
                <h:outputLink > 
                    <h:outputText value="Link"/>
                    <a4j:ajax event="click" listener="#{linkBean.linkSelectionWithLerneinheit(lerneinheit)}" render="link_panel"/> 
                </h:outputLink>
            </a4j:outputPanel>
            <a4j:outputPanel id="unlink_panel" rendered="#{linkBean.isLinkedWithLerneinheit(lerneinheit)}" >
                <h:outputLink > 
                    <h:outputText value="Unlink"/>
                    <a4j:ajax event="click" listener="#{linkBean.unlinkSelectionFromLerneinheit(lerneinheit)}" render="link_panel"/> 
                </h:outputLink>
            </a4j:outputPanel>
        </a4j:outputPanel>
    </center>
</rich:column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to render one link_panel, then you have to have unique id's for the elements.

Comment: How can i generate this when i am in a datatable? I tried #{lerneinheit.id} which would be the entity id, but then i get an error that the id attribute is not allowed to be empty.

Comment: Got it, Thanks!: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866757/assign-a-unique-client-id-to-each-richdatatable-row